# How can I insert content into a file during a Gulp build?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, stream, gulp

I managed to accomplish my task using a Gulp plugin called [gulp-insert](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-insert) like this:

```
gulp.task('compile-js', function () {
  // Minify and bundle client scripts.
  var scripts = gulp.src([
    srcDir + '/routes/**/*.js',
    srcDir + '/shared/js/**/*.js'
  ])
    // Sort angular files so the module definition appears
    // first in the bundle.
    .pipe(gulpAngularFilesort())
    // Add angular dependency injection annotations before
    // minifying the bundle.
    .pipe(gulpNgAnnotate())
    // Begin building source maps for easy debugging of the
    // bundled code.
    .pipe(gulpSourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(gulpConcat('bundle.js'))
    // Buffer the bundle.js file and replace the appConfig
    // placeholder string with a stringified config object.
    .pipe(gulpInsert.transform(function (contents) {
      return contents.replace("'{{{appConfigObj}}}'", JSON.stringify(config));
    }))
    .pipe(gulpUglify())
    // Finish off sourcemap tracking and write the map to the
    // bottom of the bundle file.
    .pipe(gulpSourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(buildDir + '/shared/js'));

  return scripts.pipe(gulpLivereload());
});
```

What I'm doing is reading our app's configuration file which is managed by the [config](https://www.npmjs.com/package/config) module on npm. Getting our config file from server-side code is a snap using `var config = require('config');`, but we're a single-page app and frequently need access to the configuration settings on the client-side. To do that I stuff the config object into an Angular service.

Here's the Angular service before gulp build.

```
angular.module('app')
  .factory('appConfig', function () {
    return '{{{appConfigObj}}}';
  });
```

The placeholder is in a string so that it's valid JavaScript for some of the other Gulp plugins that process the file first. The `gulpInsert` utility lets me insert the config like this.

```
.pipe(gulpInsert.transform(function (contents) {
  return contents.replace("'{{{appConfigObj}}}'", JSON.stringify(config));
}))
```

This works but feels a little hacky. Not to mention that it has to buffer the whole bundled file just so I can perform the operation. Is there a more elegant way to accomplish the same thing? Preferably one that allows the stream to keep flowing smoothly without buffering the whole bundle at the end?

Comment: I have taken somewhat different approach to this. I created one json file per env. dev.config.js, prod.config.js & during gulp dev/prod build i do replace my env.config.js by the appropriate config.js and my index.html includes env.config.js. This feels somewhat cleaner than search and replace in files

Comment: Sorry, but what is the problem of using buffers? Streaming is also a kind of buffering, but with smaller size. However, I really doubt that your whole bundle.js exceeds even 1 Mb, which is almost nothing nowdays.
Maybe, you are not satisfied with the overall execution time of your build. In that case you should look at using `watch` functionality.

Comment: It's a large enterprise app Dimitry. It's not too big yet, but it most definitely will be. We went with gulp for the performance gains that make build times potentially much shorter than the same setup with grunt. I'm taking care to do things properly early on in order to shave off every possible second going into the future.

Comment: @entre I do like that approach but I've opted to go with tomtastico's answer below. Do feel free to share your solution though as it very well could benefit others.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you checked [`gulp-replace-task`](https://github.com/outaTiME/gulp-replace-task)?

Something like

```js
[...]
.pipe(gulpSourcemaps.init())
.pipe(replace({
  patterns: [{
    match: '{{{appConfigObj}}}',
    replacement: config
  }],
  usePrefix: false
})
.pipe(gulpUglify())
[...]
```

Comment: Nice! Looks like [it does do the replace mid-stream](https://github.com/outaTiME/gulp-replace-task/blob/master/index.js#L26-L54) as desired instead of waiting for it all to buffer at the end. Nice find :D

Comment: this module works great! Very powerful with regular expressions + replacement functions.

Answer (score 2):

Admittedly, this feels a bit hacky, too, but maybe slightly better... I'm using [`envify`](https://github.com/hughsk/envify) and [`gulp-env`](https://github.com/moveline/gulp-env) in a React project. You could do something like this.

gulpfile.js:

```
var config = require('config');
var envify = require('envify');

gulp.task('env', function () {
    env({
        vars: {
            APP_CONFIG: JSON.stringify(config)
        }
    });
});

gulp.task('compile-js', ['env'], function () {
  // ... replace `gulp-insert` with `envify`
});
```

factory:

```
angular.module('app')
  .factory('appConfig', function () {
    return process.env.APP_CONFIG;
  });
```

Comment: Does envify still buffer the entire file before doing the replace?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know for sure. I would guess "no" because envify seems fast in my project, but that would be just a guess.

Comment: Do you end up with a variable that contains all the file contents as a string that you then do the replace work on? If you do then it's buffering the whole file into memory. The way I'm doing it is fast too, it's just that I want to stick to the gulp streaming paradigm and shave off every nanosecond that I can. This file is only going to get bigger and bigger as time goes on.

Comment: I see how you are using it for my problem now :D. I do think it might work in a streaming configuration as you suspected. Though I think I'd rather find the logic they use in the module and duplicate it. That wouldn't feel as hacky. I'll take a look :)

Comment: Dang. I was really hoping it was modifying data in place as it streamed, but [it just concatenates buffers into one big buffer](https://github.com/hughsk/envify/blob/master/custom.js#L23-L35) and does the replace operation on it all at once before flushing the buffer through to the output. Looks like I need to learn streams better and write some custom code myself. The [split](https://www.npmjs.com/package/split) and [through](https://www.npmjs.com/package/through) modules appear to be useful here. Thanks for the suggestion anyway :)

Comment: Ah. I see. Good observation.

Comment: @MrYellow tools like UglifyJS2 will remove unreachable code like this.